# How can I fix my C++ compiler as it isn't loaded by default?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Recently I had installed the Ubuntu flavour of the Linux operating system. I had opened a terminal and just wrote a sample C program to check if it is compiling. When I saved the sample file and compiled with cc a.c, errors comes that the standard library is not loaded (i.e stdio.h). When I went to help pages, it says that the C or C++ compiler doesnt gets loaded by default and we should do it ourselves.

So can anyone help me out to fix this problem, i.e to load the C/C++ compiler.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Super User.

Comment: stdio.h is not a library, if you get compilation errors please post them as well as the code so we can help you.

Comment: might I suggest (as I don't have high enough rep) the question being renamed to a question? I like this question as it's nice to see beginner stuff on these sites, so I'm not complaining, I just can't edit it myself.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: The package build-essentials contains all the standard libraries and include files needed for compiling c programs.

Comment: The meta-package is named `build-essential`, not `build-essentials`

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

will install [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), the development headers for [Glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [EGLIBC](http://www.eglibc.org/), and basic Debian package creation infrastructure.

For man pages, you will want to install the additional packages

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-dev manpages-posix-dev glibc-doc
```

Most libraries are split up into `libfoo0`, `libfoo-dev`, and `libfoo-doc` packages.  (The numeric suffix on the first package may change for each ABI revision.)  In order to use the library, you need `libfoo0`; in order to build binaries using the library, you will need `libfoo-dev`, and the purpose of `libfoo-doc` should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the beginning of your `a.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```